# "managed by your organization" in work account on home computer

Tags: google-chrome, group-policy

I'm a web development teacher. My organization uses the "managed by your organization" feature in Chrome, and policy is disabling the developer tools. During lessons, I get around this by having students use the Guest user or Firefox in the lab (this is what the IT department has said to do).

Unfortunately, the way Chrome is designed, I can't use the web inspector to grade students' homework while logged into my work user (which has all my bookmarks and passwords) even if I'm on my home computer.

Most articles related to this problem show how to delete registry keys which doesn't seem applicable if you're still logged into the organization account (the registry keys don't even exist for me). Is there any way to disable this feature entirely on a machine that I have admin rights on?

Comment: Why are your work group policies being applied to your personal machine?

Comment: @Ramhound They're not; they're being applied to *Chrome* on my personal machine.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense, only way to control Chrome on Windows like that, is with a group policy

Comment: @Ramhound It's certainly possible I've misunderstood the tutorials, but I was unable to locate the keys in regedit; HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft exists, but HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Chrome does not.

Comment: @ramhound do you know that Google doesn't have a management system without Chrome itself? It would surprise me if they didn't, considering they don't have access to the OS the way Microsoft does, on Windows computers, at least.

Comment: @aebabis you should speak with your school IT people. If you have a legit need to access the Dev section, they should have a way to enable that.

Comment: @music2myear - there are Google administrative GPO Templates

Comment: I know, but that only works for systems on a Microsoft domain. Windows has its mechanisms for handling BYOD management as well, using GP and other tools. Google doesn't have access to any of these for Google Enterprise BYOD setups like this.